# How to pass KeyEventArgs parameters to the command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

Here is my code:

**XAML:**

```
<intr:Interaction.Triggers>
    <intr:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
        <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding KeyDownEvent}" />
    </intr:EventTrigger>
</intr:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**Code**:

```
public DelegateCommand<KeyEventArgs> KeyDownEvent { get; private set; }

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
        KeyDownEvent = new DelegateCommand<KeyEventArgs>(KeyDownEventHandler);
}

private void KeyDownEventHandler(KeyEventArgs args) //args is always null
{
    try
    {
        if (args.Key == Key.System && args.SystemKey == Key.F4)
        {
            args.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

When press any key the event is fired and the `KeyDownEventHandler` is invoked, but the `args` parameter is always `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `PassEventArgsToCommand` property to `True`.

```
<intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding KeyDownEvent}"
                          PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
```

Be aware, that is the `InvokeCommandAction` from the [Microsoft XAML behaviors NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/). This is a replacement of the legacy Blend behaviors (`System.Windows.Interactivity`). The new XML namespace to use after installing the package is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors`. You can specify the property path in the command parameter with `EventArgsParameterPath`.

Alternatively, the `InvokeCommandAction` shipped with Prism will pass the event args, too, if you do not set a `CommandParameter` explicitly. It also allows to specify a property in the command parameter with `TriggerParameterPath`. For more information refer to the [documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Advanced-MVVM.html#passing-eventargs-parameters-to-the-command).

> [...] the Prism `InvokeCommandAction` uses the EventArgs parameter passed to it from the parent trigger, passing it to the associated command if the CommandParameter is not set.

The old variant of `InvokeCommandAction` does not provide an option to pass the event arguments to the command.

Comment: PassEventArgsToCommand Property gives me error: "The property 'PassEventArgsToCommand' was not found in type 'InvokeCommandAction'."

Comment: @amirhossein What is your `intr` XML namespace?

Comment: xmlns:intr="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

Comment: @amirhossein I have updated the answer with the `InvokeCommandAction` from Prism.

Comment: Thank you! first way worked great! and I think it's better than second way! however, second way doesn't worked for me!